# Pyspark getting column list into aggregation function

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a question regarding udfs in Pyspark and a specific case.
I'm trying to make a simple reusable function to aggregate values on different levels and groups.
The inputs should be:

1. Existing dataframe
2. Variables for group by (either single column or a list)
3. Variables to be aggregated (same as above)
4. Function to be applied (either a specific one or a list of them). I kept it simple to sum, avg, min,max, etc...

I got it to work on cases when I have either a single function or a list, but when it comes to the aggregation variables I get stuck on introducing a list of them to the function

```
def aggregate(dataframe,grouping,aggregation,functions):
   
   **First part works ok on single functions and single columns**

   if hasattr(aggregation,'__iter__') == False and hasattr(functions,'__iter__') == False:
    if functions == sum:
      df = dataframe.groupby(grouping).sum(aggregation)
    elif functions == avg:
       df = dataframe.groupby(grouping).avg(aggregation)
    elif functions == min:
       df = dataframe.groupby(grouping).min(aggregation)
    elif functions == max:
       df = dataframe.groupby(grouping).max(aggregation)
    elif functions == count:
       df = dataframe.groupby(grouping).count(aggregation)
    elif functions == countDistinct:
      df = dataframe.groupby(grouping).countDistinct(aggregation)

  **Here is where I got into the part I struggle with, if aggregation == [some list] it will not work

  elif hasattr(aggregation,'__iter__') == True and hasattr(functions,'__iter__') == False:
    if functions == sum:
      df = dataframe.groupby(grouping).sum(aggregation)
    elif functions == avg:
       df = dataframe.groupby(grouping).avg(aggregation)
    elif functions == min:
       df = dataframe.groupby(grouping).min(aggregation)
    elif functions == max:
       df = dataframe.groupby(grouping).max(aggregation)
    elif functions == count:
       df = dataframe.groupby(grouping).count(aggregation)
    elif functions == countDistinct:
      df = dataframe.groupby(grouping).countDistinct(aggregation)
  

  **Expression to get inputs as lists works too**     
  else:
    expression_def = [f(col(c)) for f in functions for c in aggregation]
    df = dataframe.groupby(grouping).agg(*expression_def)
  return df
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `agg` method:

```
def aggregate(dataframe, grouping, aggregation, functions):
    if hasattr(aggregation, "__iter__"):
        return dataframe.groupBy(grouping).agg({f"{item}": f"{functions}" for item in aggregation})
    else:
        return dataframe.groupBy(grouping).agg({f"{aggregation}": f"{functions}"})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can save yourself a lot of writing by just using agg() function.

Example:

```
grouping = ["A", "B", "C"]
aggregation = {"A": "max", "B": "avg"}
df = dataframe.groupBy(grouping).agg(agregation)
```

That will also help you with aggregation over multiple columns, because you can pass it as a dict of aggregation functions over columns.

In your case that would look something like:

```
aggregation = {"A": "max", "B": "max": "C":"max"}
```

Ref.:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=agg#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.agg